# Как перенаправить с папки на поддомен?

Tags: .htaccess

Как перенаправить с адреса

```
site.ru/image/каие-то_символы
```

на

```
каие-то_символы.site.ru
```

?

Пробовал

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|)site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^image/(+*)$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.%{HTTP_HOST}/$ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?site\.ru$
RewriteRule ^image/(.+)$ http://$1.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```